# validating xml against xsd ignores extra elements

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I am trying to validate a XML file against a XSD file but extra elements I add to the XML are not recognized as wrong.

xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="https://myschema.test.de"
           xmlns="https://myschema.test.de"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    
    <xs:element name="items" type="itemsType">
        <xs:complexType >
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element  type="xs:string" name="id"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="listrelativepath"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="filename"/>
                            <xs:element name="fields" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="field"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="localstorage">
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--File Backup Generated 05/09/2022 16:53:53
v1.0-->
<items xmlns="http://myschema.test.de" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="https://myschema.test.de/xml/schema.xsd">
  <item>
    <ElementNotBelongingHere />
    <id>1</id>
    <listrelativepath>202010 H3D/Antragsakte/Externe Stellungnahme (ohne EIB,NAM,SAC)</listrelativepath>
    <filename />
    <fields>
      <field FileLeafRef="Placeholder.docx" />
    </fields>
    <localstorage>C:\Users\prupprecht\Documents\20220110.txt</localstorage>
  </item>
</items>
```

the xml validates but has an extra element not belonging in the Schema. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XSD.

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://myschema.test.de" xmlns:ns1="http://myschema.test.de">
  <xs:element name="items">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:item"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="item">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:id"/>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:listrelativepath"/>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:filename"/>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:fields"/>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:localstorage"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="listrelativepath" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="filename">
    <xs:complexType/>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="fields">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:field"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="field">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="FileLeafRef" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="localstorage" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

The schema itself is not valid, so you should never have got as far as using it to validate an instance document. Saxon (running within Oxygen) reports:

```
Description: A <complexType> element must not appear as a child
  of an <xs:element> with a @type attribute
Start location: 7:47
```

If I fix that, I get an error because the namespace of the source document doesn't match the target namespace of the schema (http vs https).

If I fix that, I get three validation errors:

```
Description: Attribute @schemaLocation is not allowed on element <items>
Start location: 4:151

Description: In content of element <item>: The content model does not allow element 
  <Q{.../myschema.test.de}ElementNotBelongingHere> to appear as the first child. 
  Expected <Q{.../myschema.test.de}id>. 
Start location: 6:34

Description: Attribute @FileLeafRef is not allowed on element <field>
Start location: 11:50
```

So I don't know what you're doing wrong if validation appeared to succeed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I use ootb powershell tools. I will investigate